# How to generate xml with illegal character in tag

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

Am trying to generate xml from my table data. one of column name has `&`(illegal character). So while generating xml am getting the following error.

> Msg 6850, Level 16, State 1, Line 955 Column name 'a&b' contains an
>   invalid XML identifier as required by FOR XML; '&'(0x0026) is the
>   first character at fault.

Here is an example

```
SELECT [a&b] ='A'
FOR xml path(''), root('head')
```

Expected result :

```
<head>
  <a&b>A</a&b>
</head>
```

Is there way to do this in sql ?

Comment: you have always the '&' ?

Comment: @YogeshSharma - Yes always `&` will be present in column name

Comment: i think all answers are useful, but you just check by creating one xml file having data as above & then run in your browser (I.E., Chrome, ...) wht output it will give ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected result is definitely invalid xml:

XML is meant to be as an interchangeable format which can be converted to a (semi)-human readable **string** format. The need to encode the XML as string must define some characters as *magic*, namely `<, > and &`. These characters **must be escaped** in order not to disturb the XML's markups:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE([ab] NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(N'forbidden characters will be escaped &><');

SELECT * FROM @tbl FOR XML PATH('root');
```

The result

```
<root>
  <ab>forbidden characters will be escaped &amp;&gt;&lt;</ab>
</root>
```

An appropriate tool will automatically re-escape these entities while reading the XML.

But element's and attribute's nodes are much more restricted! This table contains a *bad column*:

```
DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE([a&b] NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES(N'dummy');
SELECT * FROM @tbl2 FOR XML RAW;
```

`FOR XML PATH` will throw an error, but `FOR XML RAW` will come back with this:

```
<row a_x0026_b="dummy" />
```

The problem is, that these replacements **are not re-encoded**:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=(SELECT * FROM @tbl2 FOR XML RAW);
SELECT @xml.value(N'local-name((/row/@*)[1])',N'nvarchar(max)')
```

The attribute's name is returned as `a_x0026_b`.

My first advise is: **Never do that! Don't use forbidden characters within the XML's markup!**

You might use something like

```
SELECT column1
      ,column2
      ,[My&bad<column] AS SomeOtherName
      ,column4
FROM myTable
FOR XML PATH('root')
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can change to XML raw:

```
SELECT [a&b] ='A'
FOR xml raw, root('head')
```

This will change the structure of your XML but it will not throw an error and it is well formed XML.

```
<head>
  <row a_x0026_b="A" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `REPLACE` with a special string which not occurs inside your XML-data:

```sql
DECLARE @myXML varchar(MAX)
SET @myXML=(SELECT 'a.123ASPECIALSTRING123.b'='A' FOR xml path(''), root('head'))
SELECT REPLACE(@myXML, '.123ASPECIALSTRING123.', '&');
```

Test example: http://rextester.com/BYJYY1222

---

But note: `&` is not an allowed char for XML-element names.

Means the result will be a badly formed XML.

> XML elements must follow these naming rules:
>
> - Element names are case-sensitive
> - Element names must start with a letter or underscore
> - Element names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
> - Element names can contain letters, digits, hyphens, underscores, and periods
> - Element names cannot contain spaces
>
> Any name can be used, no words are reserved (except xml).

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_elements.asp

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But result should be `xml` not string. So we cannot have `&` in tag's. No way to get the illegal characters in tags right..

Comment: @Pரதீப் I don't think that SQL-Server will output invalid XML in any way...but maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: I did quite some research on this. Looks like it is not possible. I just need that confirmation :) Lets wait for someone to confirm or come up with an answer.

Comment: You can output the result to a file with `exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp ....'`. - But still it will be invalid XML.